# Cleaning strings in sparklyr using regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, sparklyr

I'm trying to clean strings in a table in sparklyr using regexp_replace.  I need to remove both multiple spaces between words and specific whole words.

## Establish Spark Connection

```
pharms <- spark_read_parquet(sc, 'pharms', 's3/path/to/pharms', infer_schema = TRUE, memory = FALSE)
```

## Vector to clean

The df vector I want to clean looks like this, but it is within a table in the sparklyr connection:

```
drug_strings <- c("tablomiacin sodium tab      mg", "nsaid  caps  mg")
```

The desired output once the regex processes the data would be something like this:

## Desired Outcomes

```
[1] "tablomiacin sodium", "nsaid"
```

## Attempts

I've tried various combinations used in regex such as:

```
pharms_cln <- pharms %>%
  distinct(drug_strings)%>%
  mutate(new_strings=regexp_replace(drug_strings, "\\b(caps|mg|tab)\\b", ""))

pharms_cln <- pharms %>%
  distinct(drug_strings)%>%
  mutate(new_strings=regexp_replace(drug_strings, "\\s+", ""))
```

But they all just replace all letters or substrings and not just the individual word or print an error related to hive.  Similarly the efforts I've tried to remove blanks spaces just seem to remove the letter 's'.

Comment: So what's the rule govering the sought replacement: anything preceding `caps|mg|tab`?

Comment: There's two whitespaces between `nsaid  caps`, correct?

Comment: Yes basically I already cleaned out non alpha characters.

Comment: Does the new updated answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rule for the sought replacement "anything preceding `caps|mg|tab`", then this may work:

Data:

```
drug_strings <- c("tablomiacin sodium tab      mg", "nsaid  caps  mg")
```

Solution:

```
trimws(gsub("\\b(tab|mg|caps)\\b", "", drug_strings))
[1] "tablomiacin sodium" "nsaid"
```

If for some reason you need to use `str_extract`, you can do this:

```
str_extract(gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", drug_strings), "\\b\\w+\\b(\\s\\b\\w+\\b)*(?=\\s\\b(tab|mg|caps)\\b)")
```

This first reduces all multiple white space characters to just one such char, and then does the extraction.

Comment: That gets me part ways there.  There are complex drugs that have more than one word in them  A work around is to tokenize and then paste, but that is inefficient.  I'll edit my question to reflect the complexity thank you!

Comment: Updated with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who knows regex could certainly streamline this code, but the following using using the str_remove function from the stringr package.

```
drug_strings <- c("tablomiacin tab      mg", "nsaid  caps  mg")

drug_strings <- data.frame(drug_strings)

drug_strings <- drug_strings %>% 
mutate(new_strings=str_remove(drug_strings, "\\b(caps|mg|tab)\\b")) %>% 
mutate(new_strings=str_remove(new_strings, "\\s+")) %>% 
mutate(new_strings = str_remove(new_strings, "mg"))
``
```

Comment: Let me try this in sparklyr. That's what I'm looking for.  Maybe my example needs to better reflect that.

Comment: It results in a Hive related error:
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'STR_REMOVE'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7